# Manually splitting a query into two queries reduces execution time by 90%. How can I force query optimizer to do the right thing?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have two queries that are entirely equivalent in their results.

Method 1: Do everything in one query (takes 235 seconds)

```
with stage1 as(
   ... BLAH BLAH BLAH...
)
SELECT ... FROM stage1 ....
```

Method 2: hold intermediate data in mytemptable (total about 18 seconds)

```
-- query 2a
CREATE TABLE mytemptable AS 
...BLAH BLAH BLAH...                   -- takes about 2 seconds

-- query 2b
SELECT ... FROM mytemptable ...        -- takes about 16 seconds
```

Method 2 appears to be *WAY* faster because it uses a nested loop, seq scan, index scan instead of some merge join approach. Is there a sane way to force the faster query plan on query 1? (I have no need for saving the temporary table...)

-- Update 1 --

The right thing is to use a nested loop while merge join is horribly slow.

It appears I can get sane behavior with a single query by adding `set local enable_mergejoin=false;` but I wonder if there's a better way?

### Full source of original queries:

#### Method 1

```
EXPLAIN analyze
with stage1 as(
SELECT DISTINCT permno, d.date, d.date/100 as yyyymm
    FROM eb2.msk_bt_datesandstuff
    JOIN mycrsp.trading_dates d ON (rdq_i <= d.i and d.i <= rdq_i + 2) OR (fdate_i <= d.i and d.i <= fdate_i + 2)
    WHERE repm_shares_pp > 0
)

SELECT yyyymm, AVG(ret)
FROM stage1 t
JOIN q_stock.dsf dsf ON dsf.permno = t.permno AND dsf.date = t.date
GROUP BY yyyymm
ORDER BY yyyymm
```

Note q_stock.dsf has a primary key on (permno, date) and I have done `analyze q_stock.dsf;`

#### Explain Analyze result for query 1

```
Sort  (cost=66540412.41..66540412.91 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=235793.281..235793.310 rows=135 loops=1)
  Sort Key: t.yyyymm
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 31kB
  CTE stage1
    ->  Unique  (cost=45289896.52..47173580.31 rows=39876540 width=12) (actual time=1612.561..1914.188 rows=163223 loops=1)
          ->  Sort  (cost=45289896.52..45760817.47 rows=188368379 width=12) (actual time=1612.559..1817.441 rows=349028 loops=1)
                Sort Key: msk_bt_datesandstuff.permno, d.date, ((d.date / 100))
                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8856kB
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=31.39..9742058.04 rows=188368379 width=12) (actual time=3.102..894.148 rows=349028 loops=1)
                      ->  Seq Scan on msk_bt_datesandstuff  (cost=0.00..2080.69 rows=67809 width=16) (actual time=2.179..50.339 rows=67815 loops=1)
                            Filter: (repm_shares_pp > 0::double precision)
                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on trading_dates d  (cost=31.39..108.91 rows=2778 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=5 loops=67815)
                            Recheck Cond: (((msk_bt_datesandstuff.rdq_i <= i) AND (i <= (msk_bt_datesandstuff.rdq_i + 2))) OR ((msk_bt_datesandstuff.fdate_i <= i) AND (i <= (msk_bt_datesandstuff.fdate_i + 2))))
                            Heap Blocks: exact=72014
                            ->  BitmapOr  (cost=31.39..31.39 rows=2941 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=67815)
                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trading_dates_i_idx  (cost=0.00..15.00 rows=1471 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=3 loops=67815)
                                        Index Cond: ((msk_bt_datesandstuff.rdq_i <= i) AND (i <= (msk_bt_datesandstuff.rdq_i + 2)))
                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trading_dates_i_idx  (cost=0.00..15.00 rows=1471 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=3 loops=67815)
                                        Index Cond: ((msk_bt_datesandstuff.fdate_i <= i) AND (i <= (msk_bt_datesandstuff.fdate_i + 2)))
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=19366821.95..19366824.45 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=235793.000..235793.120 rows=135 loops=1)
        Group Key: t.yyyymm
        ->  Merge Join  (cost=17586928.66..19060390.61 rows=61286269 width=12) (actual time=171508.569..235548.161 rows=163180 loops=1)
              Merge Cond: ((t.permno = dsf.permno) AND (t.date = dsf.date))
              ->  Sort  (cost=7194721.95..7294413.30 rows=39876540 width=16) (actual time=2206.763..2333.899 rows=163223 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: t.permno, t.date
                    Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 4784kB
                    ->  CTE Scan on stage1 t  (cost=0.00..797530.80 rows=39876540 width=16) (actual time=1612.565..1996.972 rows=163223 loops=1)
              ->  Materialize  (cost=10392206.71..10595963.09 rows=40751276 width=24) (actual time=169281.705..211131.879 rows=28454152 loops=1)
                    ->  Sort  (cost=10392206.71..10494084.90 rows=40751276 width=24) (actual time=169281.700..196431.128 rows=28454152 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: dsf.permno, dsf.date
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 942416kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on dsf  (cost=0.00..2734006.76 rows=40751276 width=24) (actual time=2.293..73874.003 rows=28460488 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.597 ms
Execution time: 235941.636 ms
```

#### Explain Analyze Result for Query 1b

```
Sort  (cost=1558249.38..1558249.72 rows=135 width=12) (actual time=16634.455..16634.464 rows=135 loops=1)
  Sort Key: t.yyyymm
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 31kB
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1558242.92..1558244.61 rows=135 width=12) (actual time=16634.322..16634.357 rows=135 loops=1)
        Group Key: t.yyyymm
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..1556982.65 rows=252054 width=12) (actual time=0.348..16425.602 rows=163180 loops=1)
              ->  Seq Scan on deleteme2 t  (cost=0.00..2515.23 rows=163223 width=16) (actual time=0.021..60.422 rows=163223 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using dsf_pkey on dsf  (cost=0.56..9.50 rows=2 width=24) (actual time=0.096..0.098 rows=1 loops=163223)
                    Index Cond: ((permno = t.permno) AND (date = t.date))
Planning time: 3.336 ms
Execution time: 16634.577 ms
```

Comment: Try to move the CTE into a derived table ("inline view") instead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no luck. It still wants to do a horrible merge join even with a derived table. `set local enable_mergejoin=false;` does the trick but that feels like a horrible hack...  Will the SQL gods look down on me if I do that? Or is that an acceptable move?

Comment: I encounter this routinely...  not constantly (or even frequently), but often enough that it puzzles me.  I seriously hope you get a good answer.

Comment: I don't know how to rewrite the query so that it is processed quickly, but it is clear why the version with the temporary table performs better: the autovacuum daemon must have run and calculated accurate statistics on the temporary table. On a CTE, no statistics can be collected, and the horrible misestimate of the CTE size is what causes the problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks! That makes perfect sense and actually is quite helpful for the future! I'm not that experienced with DB programming and it *totally* eluded me what was going on. For this narrow problem, the `set enable_mergejoin=false` hack method appears to work well enough, but I feel a lot better now that I understand what was happening.